# Add custom methods and custom endpoints in SuiteCRM REST API V8

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

SuiteCRM version: Version 7.10.11
Sugar Version 6.5.25 (Build 344)

I am trying to add custom endpoints in REST API V8. I follow below suitecrm  documentation.

```
https://docs.suitecrm.com/developer/api/version-8/customization/
```

but its not working. seems like bugs in documentation and there is no sample code available in documentation.

I have check API code file and custom endpoint path is.

```
// Load Custom Routes
```

$customRouteFiles = (array) glob($paths->getCustomLibraryPath() . '/API/v8/route/*.php');

I have create custom endpoints in "/API/v8/route/" file but its not working.

I have check documentation available for API 4_1 to add custom API method. but not available for V8 version.

```
https://docs.suitecrm.com/developer/api/api-4_1/#_adding_custom_api_methods
```

Anyone Please Suggest latest documentation links or sample code for extending endpoints and adding Custom Rest Methods in V8 . Its very difficult to understand core API code without Proper documentation.

Thanks